# Convert active directory query from VBS to Javascript for the Global Catalog

Tags: javascript, vbscript, active-directory

Can anyone fill in the blanks here.
I have been trying to get a script I could run to query all available users in the Global Catalog for active directory and finally managed it in VBS -looking for any particular username as below:

```
Const ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION = 1 


Set oGC = GetObject("GC:") 
For Each child In oGC 
Set oEntrprise = child 
Exit For 
Next 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("AD.txt", True) 

' Setup ADO. 
Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
Set oComm = CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 

oConn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject" 
oConn.Properties("ADSI Flag") = ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION 

oConn.Open 
oComm.ActiveConnection = oConn 

' Set the search command and filter. 
objFile.WriteLine(oEntrprise.ADsPath) 
oComm.CommandText = "<" & oEntrprise.ADsPath & ">;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenName=aaron*));cn,distinguishedName;subTree"
' Execute the query. 
Set oRS = oComm.Execute 

' Print the results. 
oRS.MoveFirst 
While Not oRS.EOF 
For Each field In oRS.Fields 
objFile.WriteLine(field) 
Next 
objFile.WriteLine("") 
oRS.MoveNext 
Wend 

WScript.Echo "Finished"
```

Im now trying to convert it to JS but I cannot replicate it.
I cannot find the golden answer for looping through GetObject("GC:"). For each doesnt seem to work like for like in this case. Is anyone aware of how to do this?
So in effect i need the JS equivelant of oEntrprise in the above script.

```
var oConn = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
var oComm = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Command"); 
var keyname = "samaccountname";
var keyvalue = "aaron";

oConn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject";
oConn.Properties("ADSI Flag") = 1; 

oConn.Open;
oComm.ActiveConnection = oConn;

var objRootDSE = GetObject("GC:");  
for (var i = 0; i < objRootDSE.length; i++) {
    WriteToFile("Moahhh");
    var oEntrprise = objRootDSE[i];
    oComm.CommandText = "<" + oEntrprise.ADsPath + ">;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(givenName=a*));cn,distinguishedName;subTree";
    var oRS = oComm.Execute;

}

function WriteToFile(sText){

var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var FileObject = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\builds\\LogFile.txt", 8, true,0); // 8=append, true=create if not exist, 0 = ASCII
FileObject.write(sText)

FileObject.close()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JScript you need to use an Enumerator to step over the elements of a collection

```
var objRootDSE = GetObject('GC:');
for (var childs = new Enumerator(objRootDSE) ; !childs.atEnd(); childs.moveNext()){
    var child = childs.item();
    WScript.Echo( child.Name );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggested answer - answers the impossible loop I could not solve but I have now found a way to query the Global Catalogue for users directly without a need for the loop:

```
var aoi = WScript.CreateObject("ADSystemInfo");
var gcBase = aoi.ForestDNSName;

var ado = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
ado.Provider = "ADSDSOObject";
ado.Open;
WriteToFile(aoi.ForestDNSName);
var objectList =   ado.Execute("<GC://" + gcBase + ">;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)("+keyname+"="+keyvalue+"*));cn,distinguishedName;subTree");

if(!objectList.EOF)
{
    WriteToFile(objectList("distinguishedName").value);
}

function WriteToFile(sText){

var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var FileObject = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\LogFile.txt", 8, true,0); // 8=append, true=create if not exist, 0 = ASCII
FileObject.write(sText)

FileObject.close()
}
```

Never again.
Whoever finds this I will help Google get here - Global Catalog JavaScript query for Active Directory!